# Prove there is no entire function $g$ such that $g=f $ on $\{z:|z|>1\}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider $f:\{z\in \mathbb C:|z|>1\}\to \mathbb C$ defined by $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z}$.

Prove there is no entire function $g$ such that $g=f $ on $\{z:|z|>1\}$.

Suppose there exists an entire function $g$ such that $g(z)=f(z);|z|>1$.Now $f$ maps the entire domain to the set $\{z:|z|<1\}$ and so does $g$.

Also since $z\mapsto |z|$ is continuous so the sets $\{z:|z|>1\},\{z:|z|<1\}$ are open sets.

Now $g:\{|z|>1\} \mapsto \{z:|z|<1\}$ given by $g(z)=\frac{1}{z}$.So $g$ is bounded and hence constant by Liouville's Theorem .Thus $g(z)=k ;|z|>1$.

But $\{z:|z|>1\}$ is an open set and $g$ maps an open set into a closed set which is a contradiction as analytic functions map open sets into open sets.

Thus no such function exists.

Are the arguements true?Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ for $|z|>1$, so image of the open set $\{ z\colon |z|>1\}$ is bounded.

What about remaining $z$'s? The set $\{z\colon |z|\leq 1\}$ is closed disc, so image under $g$ of that set is also bounded. Hence $g$ is bounded on $\mathbb{C}$, so it is constant.

But $g$ agrees with $f$ on $\{z\colon |z|>1\}$, and $f$ is *not constant* there, this is contradiction.

---

The statement *''But $\{z:|z|>1\}$ is an open set and $g$ maps an open set into a closed set''* is confusing. Actually (you have noted this almost) 
$g$ maps the open set $\{z\colon |z|>1\}$ *onto* an open set $\{z\colon |z|<1\}$.

You may want to say "$g$ maps that open set *into[=inside]* a closed set" This is not giving any contradiction.